# Mannequin Duplication glitch

Tags: skyrim-hearthfire, the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I looked around but cannot seem to find anything that actually answers the question of how I can stop the mannequins in my house from duplicating everything I put on them.
I had Cicero's armor on a stand and ended up switching it with Miraak's armor, but when I go inside my house it will sometimes spawns Cicero's armor and I have like... 3 sets of them.

All I want to know is how to fix this glitch, so I can use the mannequins as they are intended, for displaying my valuable armors.

Just so you know I am on Xbox 1 and have the Special Edition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In [this thread](https://elderscrolls.fandom.com/wiki/Thread:261170), user *Malac'ra* wrote down **the following pure gameplay solution** based on [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ptYY2E83UPA):

> 1. Take all duplicated armor off of mannequin.
>      Leave the area and come back (I went in and out of the cellar for this).
> 2. Add a full set of unique enchanted armor (Thieves Guild, Nightingale, Shrouded Armor, etc.) and shield (such as Targe of the
>      Blooded), leaving the duplicated armor in the mannequin's inventory.
>      Enchanted gear should appear on the mannequin over top of the
>      duplicated gear.
>      Leave the area and come back.
> 3. The old duplicated gear should be on top again. Take everything out of the mannequin's inventory. Without leaving the mannequin inventory
>      screen, add all the duplicated stuff and then all the enchanted armor
>      IN THAT ORDER. The enchanted gear should be visible on the mannequin
>      before leaving.
>      Leave the area and come back.
> 4. The enchanted gear should still be on top. Take everything out of the mannequin's inventory. Go in and out of the inventory several
>      times for good measure, then leave the area and go back.
> 5. Mannequin should now be naked and have nothing in the inventory.
>      Supposedly it's done duplicating armor now.

([Here](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/boards/615804-the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim/62849283)'s a variation on the theme. The mannequins seemingly need to be conditioned properly.)

---

For pc gamers (and completeness' sake), in that same long and winding thread about this bug, another user offers the following solution using the game's console:

> - Enter the house so that the mannequin is wearing the items it keeps duplicating;
> - go into the console and click on the mannequin;
> - type `inv`, type `removeitem` followed by the the equipped item's *baseID* [space] followed by `1` (e.g. `removeitem 13965 1`), and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> (same steps for each of the items).   This should
>     permanently remove them from the mannequin.
> - Drop the items you want on the floor and get their *baseID*;
> - go back to the mannequin;
> - type `equipitem`, followed by the *baseID* of the item on the floor (enchanted custom armor should have their own baseID) [space] `1` and
>     hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.   That should permanently equip the item on the
>     mannequin.   Then I dropped all the dozens of duplicated items on the
>     floor, clicked on them while in the console, typed `markfordelete`,
>     and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>. I did that for all the items individually.
>     Then I saved the game and restarted.

---

Some notes:

- Based on comments, this bug seems to be exclusive to the Hearthfire houses.
- The bug is fixed by the Unofficial Patch ([Xbox 1](https://bethesda.net/en/mods/skyrim/mod-detail/2947804)/[PC](https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrimspecialedition/mods/266/)), although the fix sometimes gets overridden by other mods, depending on the load order.
- There is a standalone mod for the PC addressing this bug, called 'Skyrim Mannequin Duping Bug Fix'. It can be found [here](https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/9562/?). The mod offers an update of the bugged vanilla mannequin script (*MannequinActivatorSCRIPT.pex*).

Comment: I joined this community just so I could upvote this answer. The pure gameplay solution worked perfectly for me (I'm playing it on the Switch). Thank you so much for finding it and posting it here!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can. However this has happend to me and i know 5 sets of ebony mail but when i had equipped it with something new it stopped the duping and kept the latest item.